# store.load() triggers read + create

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing a app where a list is automatically refreshed every 15 sec. To do so, I load the store every 15 sec from server (sending the params) via php page linked to a postgreSQL DB. So far, so good, and it works OK.
Buy I have noticed that every time the store is loaded, it sends two requests to the server (read + create). While the read request is necessary to load new elements to the store, the create is completely useless, because it sends the whole store as payload and receives nothing making use of the network for nothing.
How can I make the store to read, and only read, from the server when it loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some week sago I had some unexpected creates too. Googles learned me that there is an issue with Sencha with store.load(). It seems loaded records stay phantoms after loading. A store.sync() will create all records in a store that are phantoms (means they are not yet in back end). 
I have next code in my on load callbacks:

```
callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    var x = records.length;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        records[i].phantom = false;
    }
}
```

This solved my problem.